# binding with path doesn't work when first item on path is null

Tags: android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

With MvvmCross, I am trying to bind android:visibility of a TextView to a path similar to "Results.Count" with a converter set to transform the integer to visibility (if not null and greater than zero, TextView is visible).

If Results is null, it shows an error in the app output:

> [MvxBind]   1.34 Problem seen during binding execution for from
>   SearchResult.Count to Visibility - problem InvalidCastException: Null
>   object can not be converted to a value type. [MvxBind]      at
>   System.Convert.ToType (System.Object value, System.Type
>   conversionType, IFormatProvider provider, Boolean try_target_to_type)
>   [0x00000] in :0  [MvxBind]   at
>   System.Convert.ChangeType (System.Object value, System.Type
>   conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in :0  [MvxBind]   at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.ExtensionMethods.MvxTypeExtensions.MakeSafeValue
>   (System.Type propertyType, System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0  [MvxBind]   at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.MakeSafeValue
>   (System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0  [MvxBind]
>   at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.SetValue
>   (System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0  [MvxBind]
>   at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource
>   (Boolean isAvailable, System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0  MvxBind:Error:  1.34 Problem seen during binding execution
>   for from SearchResult.Count to Visibility - problem
>   InvalidCastException: Null object can not be converted to a value
>   type.MvxBind:Error:  1.34 Problem seen during binding execution for
>   from SearchResult.Count to Visibility - problem InvalidCastException:
>   Null object can not be converted to a value type.       at
>   System.Convert.ToType (System.Object value, System.Type
>   conversionType, IFormatProvider provider, Boolean try_target_to_type)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at System.Convert.ChangeType
>   (System.Object value, System.Type conversionType, IFormatProvider
>   provider) [0x00000] in :0

The converter does not get called. 
I would had expected the converter to be called in this case, like in Silverlight or WPF.

I tried to debug this issue myself by adding the MvvmCross by source code (I added all the necessary projects from github).
I setup breakpoints in different methods showed in the exception call stack (example: Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.ExtensionMethods.MvxTypeExtensions.MakeSafeValue), but when running, the breakpoints were not hit, they were ignored by debugger.

Strange thing is that setting a breakpoint in other parts of the MvvmCross source code (like in the MvxAndroidSetup) worked.

Beside the issue with the converter, I would like to know how to make the breakpoints work in the MvvmCross code. It would allow me to understand more and even participate to the dev if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are small differences between the binding paths/calculation for MvvmCross versus Xaml.

In particular, we know `FallbackValue` is interpreted and used differently. This different behaviour:

- occurs on line [MvxFullBinding.cs#L109](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding/Bindings/MvxFullBinding.cs#L109)
- is logged in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/297.

If you have additional test cases to add to that list, then please upload them as GitHub repos and link them to that case. (But don't expect 'very quick' changes/fixes to that binding code - as changing it could break a lot of apps that now rely on it and as `MvxValueConverters` are often built to be much more type specific than traditional Microsoft `IValueConverter` ones)

---

In the meantime, for this particular case:

- a `FallbackValue` may work for you as a workaround (but may be an enum fallback value may be hard to do in xml)
- or you could use a custom binding
- or you could manipulate the ViewModel structure.

---

As for breakpoints not working in PCLs with Xamarin.Android, this is logged in a lot of places and has a been a major pain for over 6 months. According to https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8209 this is apparently now fixed on Alpha channel, but will probably never appear back in 4.6.

Comment: I've had this same issue today. It was kinda late so I just turned off the PC and came to bed. Now ai found this answer here. Thank you Opcoder  the question and slodge for the answer. Tomorrow I think I'll go with the custom bind option. I like creating custom binds :)

Comment: Thank you very much Stuart. I previously read about PCL debugging issues, but I thought it was about VisualStudio. I am using the Xamarin Studio, and the breakpoints are not hit. I also have other problems like sometimes getting error on compiling and it won't work unless I do a 'Rebuild All' first, after which the error magically disappear. Stuart, I wonder how you are able to develop and debug MVVMCross issues with the debugger not hitting the breakpoints. I am going to try see if Debug.Break is available and will trigger the debugger.

Comment: Hi Stuart, is there a specific reason why binding paths are interpreted differently than XAML? I tried your suggestion FallbackValue=ViewStates.Visible but it doesn't work. Doing a custom binding only for this reason seems a bit too much, especially since I am binding 4 controls to different properties of that Results model. It sounds like I have to implement 4 custom bindings. I wonder if I could implement my own kind of binding to override the MVVMCross behavior, is it possible? Unfortunately without debugging, it's hard for me to understand how it works and what to change...

Comment: Comments aren't really that usable for the length of question you asked... I have no idea how I'd fit an answer here either!

Comment: After spending some time trying to understand the code, I think I found a simple fix. https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding/Bindings/MvxFullBinding.cs#L109 should be 'if (isAvailable || _bindingDescription.FallbackValue == null)'. It shouldn't break any current apps which rely on a value set for FallbackValue.